# Temperature/PH/Humidity sensors Wireless?

Tags: pi-4, bluetooth, sensor, wireless, esp8266

I am designing an irrigation system. I have already put in place the pump piece, piloted by the Raspberry through a relay.
Please note that this is an outdoor system, so the less wires are there the better.
Now I would like to add some sensors such as humidity/ph/temperature; of course, I can do that buying cheap sensors and wire them up to the rasp. but if possible I would like to avoid that.
Is anyone aware of a way where I can use Bluetooth or similar wireless techs by which send ing metrics to the rasp, instead of wiring up?
Solutions with some battery are also an option.
Thanks for any suggestion

EDIT:
After some research and also thanks to one of the comments below, I think that using ESP8266 with WIFI to connect to Raspberry can be a good solution. It is also true that, now, the problem is to understand how to set up a solar charger to allow it to work for a while.

Comment: Lots of variables about range and battery life, what you want to measure etc, but the answer is yes. Whether you want to [buy](https://www.beaconzone.co.uk/sensor) or [make](https://learn.adafruit.com/bluetooth-le-broadcastnet-sensor-node-raspberry-pi-wifi-bridge)

Comment: ideally, ph/humidity and temperature are my targets. Battery life, something like 3 to 6 months is something reasonable to me.

Comment: How about this? (1) "ESP8266 Soil Moisture Sensor US$16":
https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32746901878.html. Cheers.

Comment: ESP8266 seems to be a good option, even though some battery life problems need to be fixed, maybe through a solar cell.